# Root grant permission isn't retained through app restart

Tags: android, root

Using the latest RootTools, when getting root shell access `shell = RootTools.getShell(true);`, SuperSU asks the user for root permission - even though it was granted before.

For that session of app execution, it will retain these permission and will not ask again. But once restarted from Android Studio's debugger, it will ask for root permission again.

In the SuperSU app, my app is listed with `Granted` status.

Why is the permission not retained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it does retain through app restart, but it is not retained if code is changed and reinstalled on the device.

SuperSU probably remembers the signature of app for granted app list, but rebuilding and installing a modified app changes the signature, thus leading SuperSU to ask for permission again.